# Undefined class constant 'DUMP_OBJECT_AS_MAP'

Tags: php, yii2, swagger, openapi, swagger-php

I'm getting following errors when I run openapi command to generate swagger file.

Command

```
#vendor/bin/openapi api/modules/v3/controllers/AbcController.php swagger

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool 
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool 
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool 
Exception: Undefined class constant 'DUMP_OBJECT_AS_MAP'
```

----------------------swagger annotations-------------

Top of the controller class

```
/**

@OA\Info(title="Search API", version="1.0.0")
*/
```

Above getBookmark action

```
 /**
 * @OA\Get(
 *   tags={"Tag"},
 *   path="/get-bookmarks",
 *   summary="Summary",
 *   @OA\Response(response=200, description="OK"),
 *   @OA\Response(response=401, description="Unauthorized"),
 *   @OA\Response(response=404, description="Not Found")
 * )
 */
```

I'm using following extension to generate swagger file

https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/genxoft/yii2-oas3

===================UPDATE========================

composer.json

[image]

===================Update 2 =====================

```
symfony/yaml                      v2.8.52     Symfony Yaml Component
```

Anyone can help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The annotations look ok to me; `DUMP_OBJECT_AS_MAP` is a const on the symfony Yaml class so either that installation is corrupt or very old?!

It sure would be interesting to see where the `Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool` message comes from.

Comment: I have updated the question with composer.json. Do you have any idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: Looks reasonable. More interesting might be what the  `composer show` command displays for symfony/yaml. You could also look at `vendor/symfony/yaml/Yaml.php to see if the const exists.

Comment: Updated question with composer show output. Version of symfony/yaml                   is v2.8.52. And there is no constant called DUMP_OBJECT_AS_MAP in vendor/symfony/yaml/Yaml.php file. It seems I'm using very old one of symfony/yaml

Comment: I tried to update with symfony/yaml to ^5.0. There was an issue was in with "codeception/codeception" : "2.0.*". So I changed codeception to "*" and all extension were updated. Issue was in codeception.  Now it is updated to "4.1.31". Now openapi commands are running. Thanks for your help.